# Required Field Missing, Upsert Fail

Tags: apex, error

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Account]:
>   [Account]

I am trying to upsert a List of objects which has a Master-Detail relationship with Account. The objects being the Detail and Account is the master.
I do not know how to even fill that Account field, but the field should match the account Id, for the account detail page I am on. Anyone know what is going on?

```
...
private void Data()

DetailList = [
        SELECT Id, Name, Account__c
               FROM Account_Detail__c LIMIT 900

            ];

public void Detail(){

Data();

    Account_Detail__c j = new Account_Detail__c;

    for(loops over a certain amount of times)
    {

            Account_Detail__c j = new Account_Detail__c();
            j.name ='blank';

            detailList.add(j);


    }

    upsert DetailList;


}

...
```

Comment: Can you add some code that illustrates your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the Account on the new `Account_Detail__c` records. Try do something like this:

```
for(Account a : loops over a certain amount of times) {
    Account_Detail__c j = new Account_Detail__c();
    j.name ='blank';
    j.AccountId = a.Id;
    detailList.add(j);
}
```